# Code doesn't add rows to table (HTML / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table, parent-child

I am working on my website and I want to make a table with a number of rows equal to the length of array game_names, using Javascript. The whole code is:

```
var game_names = [
  "first_game",
  "second_game",
  "third_game",
  "fourth_game",
  "fifth_game"
];

var parent = document.getElementById("games");

for (i=0;i<=10;i++){
    var child = document.createElement("tr");
    var node = document.createTextNode("hi!");
    child.appendChild(node);
    parent.appendChild(child);
}
```

In the HTML code is an empty table (without any cells) and with the id "games". The code:

```
<table id="games" border="10px" align="center" width="100px">         
</table>
```

For some reason the code doesn't add any rows to the table. I tested that the code runs down when the page is loaded (I put an alert("hi!") to the beginning of the code and it worked). I have no idea what's wrong...

Comment: Please edit the question title. *Something doesn't want to work* is neither descriptive, nor helpful for future readers.

Comment: `tr` can't show text, you need a `td` element to add the text, and then append the `td` to the `tr`.

Comment: You need `<td>` elements, but the code works fine in modern browsers that correct markup: https://jsfiddle.net/ewp85sz2/

Comment: just tested in in firefox and it worked :/

Comment: Works for me (firefox and IE11) https://jsfiddle.net/q1541anq/

Comment: @BenM Looks like [the markup is not corrected](https://jsfiddle.net/5eykb44z/), but the text shows, though.

Comment: There are smarter ways to debug than to put `alert('hi')` at the beginning of the script. That alone does not give you much info...

Comment: That's true that I should put in a td tag, but I should see an empty row in my table. Unfortunatelly I don't see any...

Comment: Please create a fiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Could it be that you run that code before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: I put the script into the <head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work but would makes strange html. Rows (tr elements) should contain cells (td elements). And your not iterating over your game_names array your just iterating from 0 to ten. See my example of your code below.

```
var game_names = [
  "first_game",
  "second_game",
  "third_game",
  "fourth_game",
  "fifth_game"
];

var parent = document.getElementById("games");


for (i=0;i<=game_names.length;i++){
    var childRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var childCell = document.createElement("td");
    var node = document.createTextNode("hi!");
    childRow.appendChild(childCell);
    childCell.appendChild(node);
    parent.appendChild(childRow);
}
```

Comment: Yes I changed the iterating btw, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the problem. I put the script after the table, because it was in the head tag! Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Why did you accept an answer which **didn't say that** then?